# AVERAGEIF Excel function into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: average

Alright, I was able to get it to get this formula working within excel:

=AVERAGEIFS($B$8:$B$88,$B$3:$B$83,"Coupons",$B$4:$B$84,"Holiday")

The formula averages the Open Rates for specific data-sets depending on their Type and Sub Type.

If B3 equals Coupons and B4 equals Holiday then paste the Average of the Open Rates for all the campaigns that contain the first two attributes into another spreadsheet.

As we all know, Google Spreadsheet does not recognize AVERAGEIF. I have been attempting to make a hybrid with the Formula Array function coupled with either FILTER or AVERAGE to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

[Image of spreadsheet](http://imageshack.us/a/img833/8130/atf2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

`=arrayformula(AVERAGE(IF($B$3:$B$83="Coupons",IF($B$4:$B$84="Holiday",$B$8:$B$88))))`

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this but the above version gives me a "DIV/0!" error: No valid data. Appreciate the help regardless.

Comment: I think this getting close, but I feel the formula needs to have a third IF= function in order to paste the 'Open Rate' data.

Comment: I certainly have the formula working in a sample doc - DIV/0! would indicate that there are no values to average - either the criteria aren't met or there are no numbers

Comment: I simply used the ranges you specified in the question - the setup is a little odd, perhaps you can confirm how it works - if B3="Coupons" and B4="Holiday" B8 will be added to the average and the same applies shifted by one row at a time, e.g. if B13="coupons" and B14="holiday" B18 will be added to the average - is that how you understand it?

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Google Docs has an [averageif](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529) function